# Rollup not fulfilling peer dependency for imported dependency

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I have a package **"Child"** which has a *peer* dependency for `react-router-dom`

I have a package **"Parent"** which has a ***non**-peer* dependency on `react-router-dom.`

I use rollup to package **Child**. Then I `yarn link @myCompany/Child` into **Parent**.

^^ the above all works as expected ^^

When I try to rollup **parent** I get

> 'react-router-dom' is imported by `..\Child\dist\index.es.js`, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency

Rollup continues and produces `\dist\index.es.js` for **Parent**

Inside `index.es.js` the references for **Parent** for `react-router-dom` are bundled as expected.

I expected the references for **Child** to do the same but I still have `import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';` in the "Child area" of the bundle

How do I have the Child package's calls to react-router-dom also get bundled instead of expected an external dependency?